# Simple animation / css property using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I have a simple page with a main page `content-wrapper` and a sidebar in the right `#sidebar-right`

I'm trying to make the content have a margin to the right so it doesn't override the sidebar and it extends when it's hidden

I'm trying to make a simple animation for this but it's not working. It doesn't do anything. H**ow can I make a smooth animation** with the same timings so I can put a margin and start pushing the sidebar to the left?

```
 var rightSidebarOpen = false;
$('#toggle-right-sidebar').click(function () {
    if(rightSidebarOpen) {
        $('#sidebar-right').hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
        $('.content-wrapper').css('margin-right', "0");
    }
    else {
        $('#sidebar-right').show("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
        $('.content-wrapper').css('margin-right', "205px");
    }
    rightSidebarOpen = !rightSidebarOpen;
});
```

Comment: can you write down your `HTML` too?

Comment: any help? plsssssssss

Comment: I need HTML Code also

Answer (score 0):

If you want to animate the margin, use jQuery .animate():

```
if(rightSidebarOpen) {
   $('.content-wrapper').animate({marginLeft: '-=205px'}, 1000)
} else {
   $('.content-wrapper').animate({marginLeft: '205px'}, 1000)
}
```